# How to install windows7 in external devices?

Tags: windows-7

i have 512 Gb  pocket hard disk in this pocket hard disk i want to install Windows 7 . how can install Windows 7 in this hard disk and also want to create partition 
, if there is any alternative way is available please explain.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: This is not a programming question, and therefore is off-topic for StackOverflow. The [help] has more information about the types of questions that should be asked here. You may be able to get help on another [se] site such as [su]. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Windows 7 cannot be installed on any drive that Windows identifies as removable. Depending on how your system is configured you might be able to  install the OS on an eSATA drive, which appears to the operating system as an internal fixed drive.

Resource>> http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/8f381e7f-77d2-4739-a072-7e1becfca506/can-i-install-windows7-onto-an-external-usb-hard-drive?forum=w7itproinstall